# Android marshmallow app is not able read sms received broadcast and read from sms service provider.

Tags: android, sms, android-6.0-marshmallow, runtime-permissions

Even I am granting run time permission for read sms, I am not able to received broadcast for incoming sms and Cursor return by Content Provider is also returning 0 data every time while reading sms inbox.

Any idea why?

Comment: perhaps you should re-register your broadcast receiver?

Comment: @rocknow its register in manifest.

Comment: this is what i'm talking about. it was registered when it was not permitted to get sms events. it may be a reason

Answer (score 0):

Check whether your application has the permission to read sms in your phone.

It may happen that targeted sdk version is less than 23 and you are only providing permission in the manifest and not programmatically checking for the permission explicitly.

Comment: no my target is 23 and run time permission is implemented

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the priority of the filter 100 in the manifest file.
Why use `ContentProvider` for Broadcast messages if the method `onRecieve` possible to get the message?
Also, check method the onRecieve, this method should be performed as quickly as possible. You can connect the service for time-consuming operations.
If you granted `RECEIVE_SMS`, but not the `READ_SMS` then `ContentProvider` 
should not work.

Comment: Also try add android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" in declaration receiver's in manifest file

Comment: i have tried same but its not working in version M.

Hey man don't be sorry for what you don't be. 

Thanks for answer.

Comment: Give block declaration of receiver and permission in manifest and code of the receiver, please